# Redirect to Custom 404 error in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

I have added `404` custom page in `Sitecore SXA`. This is working fine if we don't have a page. However, this is not working on the `media items`. if we don't have a media item showing this error `/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx` Instead of custom page.

Could someone assist me with how I can redirect it to a custom page(`404`) in Sitecore SXA?

Comment: Did you try this - https://www.coreysmith.co/sxa-media-and-layout-not-found/?
You need to create separate media handler.

Comment: No I have not tried this. Do we have default Sitecore sxa feature for this instead of custom code ?

Comment: Not I am aware of for Media items.

Comment: 404 handler doesn't support media items, pages only. media can be shared across many sites thus it would be impossible in some cases to figure out which site's 404 should be displayed.